# assign the youngest and oldest value from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

```
...
  [188]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "1201"
    ["coins_id"]=>
    string(2) "22"
    ["price"]=>
    string(8) "11.42033"
    ["time"]=>
    string(19) "2018-04-19 09:45:56"
  }
...
  [534]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "9391"
    ["coins_id"]=>
    string(2) "22"
    ["price"]=>
    string(8) "17.87132"
    ["time"]=>
    string(19) "2018-04-19 10:09:17"
  }
...
```

I want to calculate the percentage difference in the price, however I do not know how to assign the youngest and the oldest value to variables. In this json, always the older value has a smaller `id`. The common value is `coins_id`.

```
$price_young = //price with id = 534;
$price_old = //price with id = 188;
$percent_diffrent = (1 - $price_old / $price_young) * 100;
```

Comment: Why is 188 and 534 the same? id is not the same. Is it coins_id that is the matching value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [max()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) and [min()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) along with [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$price_array = array_column($array,'price'); // get all prices in an array

$price_young = (float)max($price_array); // get max latest price
$price_old = (float)min($price_array); // get min old price
$percent_diffrent = (1 - $price_old / $price_young) * 100;
```

***A hard-coded example:-*** https://eval.in/990963

Comment: better to go with `float` conversion, because your price have decimal values

Comment: @michal  glad to help you :):).

Comment: I have one more question: In the current example, I wrote that there are only two values in JSON. How can I download the largest and lowest value if JSON would have more values ? [JSON](http://wklej.org/id/3416162/).

Comment: @michal  don't worry. `array_column()` will take care of it

Comment: Yes, only that I would like to calculate the difference percent for each pair of `coins_id`. [Eval](https://eval.in/991159)

Comment: @michal  for that please ask a new question as your current question is solved. Please don't forget to add proper input as well as your code effort in the new question.You can address me the link to the new question. If I will be free I will answer otherwise you will get an answer from someone else for sure.Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm sorry for my mistake. I added a new topic, I hope that this time I explained everything well.